# REST callback support

Tags: rest

HTTP (which doesn't support a client callback mechanism), doing asynchronous service or notification on REST is hard. So how do we implement long running transactions (which typically require asynchronicity and callback support) in REST ?

Comment: Have you heard of (long) polling?

Comment: @Jeff you mean busy waiting?

Comment: I suppose you could call it that - we use it to notify the user when his PDF documents have been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronicity: You return a 202 Accepted with a Location pointing to a resource that will give them the status of their request. In that resource you may include a hint as to when the request might be completed.

Callback Support: HTTP doesn't really do this. It's up to the client to handle.

Comment: :how we can achive, for an example to request for printing a book or any long transaction, which may take a long time to complete.Without call back support in REST it can be possible?

Comment: @user1896989 The client must hit the status resource to check if it is complete. Once it is complete, the client goes about their business.